# How to pass data between def - python

Tags: python

i am unsure if i am going about this the right way so any advice would be ace !

basically i have this code :

```
def recvCell(sock, waitFor = 0):
    while True:
        hdr = sock.recv(3)
        circid, cmd = struct.unpack(">HB", hdr[0:3])
        ln = 509
        if cmd == 7 or cmd >= 128:
            ln = struct.unpack(">H", sock.recv(2))[0]
        pl = sock.recv(ln)

        if cmd == waitFor or waitFor == 0:
            return { 'circId': circid, 'cmd': cmd, 'len': ln, 'pl': pl}

# builds a cell
def buildCell(circid, command, payload):
    cell = struct.pack(">HB", circid, command)
    if command == 7 or command >= 128:
        cell += struct.pack(">H", len(payload))
    else:
        payload += "\x00" * (509 - len(payload))

    cell += payload
    return cell

# builds the version cell's payload
def buildVersions(acceptVersions):
    pkt = ''
    for v in acceptVersions:
        pkt += struct.pack(">H", v)
    return pkt

verPl = buildVersions([ 3 ])
verCell = buildCell(0, 7, verPl)

print "Packet to send is : ", verCell
ssl_sock.send(verCell)

srv_netinfocell = recvCell(ssl_sock, 8)
#process netinfo cell here
print srv_netinfocell

def decodNetInfo(pl):
    payload = pl
    tm = struct.unpack(">L", payload[0:4])
    our_or_ip_version = struct.unpack(">B", payload[4])[0]
    our_or_addr_len = struct.unpack(">B", payload[5])[0] 
    return{}
        if our_or_addr_len == 4:
        our_op_ip = struct.unpack(">BBBB", payload[6:10]) 
        our_ip_version = 4
        num_their_ips = struct.unpack(">B", payload[10])[0]
        len_their_ips = struct.unpack(">b", payload[12][0]
```

which sends a packet, and recieves it,

what i am trying to focus on is the decodNetinfo bit

what i want to do here is to call this some how and retrieve the `pl` from the `recvCell` function if the packet recieved by this was cmd ==8

how can i pass this data from recvCell to decodNetInfo ?

THanks

edit::

```
def recvCell(sock, waitFor = 0):
    while True:
        hdr = sock.recv(3)
        circid, cmd = struct.unpack(">HB", hdr[0:3])
        ln = 509
        if cmd == 7 or cmd >= 128:
            ln = struct.unpack(">H", sock.recv(2))[0]
        pl = sock.recv(ln)

        if cmd == waitFor or waitFor == 0:
            return { 'circId': circid, 'cmd': cmd, 'len': ln, 'pl': pl}

def decodeNetInfo(pl):
    return  "in decode net info"
    return { 'pl': pl}


srv_netinfocell = recvCell(ssl_sock, 8)
decodeNetInfo(srv_netinfocell['pl'])
#process netinfo cell here
print srv_netinfocell
```

i have done this but do not get the two return statements from the decode netinfo any ideas? thanks

Comment: Could you review your indentation? Should everything after `return{}` (why return an empty dictionary?) be in the function? It will never get run there. What have *you* tried! and what was wrong with it?

Comment: everything in the revCell is fine and working, displays the right results, however when i try to pass the value pl i am not getting any reposnce from the decodeNetInfo function, so am unsure if its even being called

Comment: For one thing, you can only have one return from the function; the second will never run. For another, you don't *do anything* with the returned value. You need to assign it; it won't magically mutate `srv_netinfocell`. I suggest you read [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), same your current code makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

The return of recvCell() is the following dictionary

```
return { 'circId': circid, 'cmd': cmd, 'len': ln, 'pl': pl}
```

So after you call the function, just pass that key to your dictionary to get the value

```
srv_netinfocell = recvCell(ssl_sock, 8)
decodNetInfo(srv_netinfocell['pl'])
```

Comment: Thanks that is what i ment however now i am not getting the return values from the decodeNetInfo, is it being called ?

Comment: @user2962401 If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: @Veedrac my mistake, I thought that comment was addressed towards me. My apologies.